# How would I get Wordpress to parse /mypage/area/value as /mypage/?area=value?

Tags: url-rewriting, query-string

I have sucessfully "registered" a query key called "area" in functions.php like so:

```
function myplugin_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'area';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'myplugin_register_query_vars' );
```

This allows me to have a page with a key/value pair like: http://example.com/mypage/?area=newyork

Note that in this example, "mypage" is the slug for an existing Wordpress Page. Also, I'm using the Wordpress Theme to handle the slightly different output for each different value for the "area" key...

In any case, I would now like the URL to be like:

- http://example.com/mypage/area/newyork
- http://example.com/mypage/area/newjersey

These URLs would be parsed as:

- http://example.com/mypage/?area=newyork
- http://example.com/mypage/?area=newjersey

How would I go about getting Wordpress to parse /mypage/area/value as /mypage/?area=value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`add_rewrite_rule`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) is very handy for this use, first add your custom rule for this:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    return add_rewrite_rule(
        '([^/]+)/area/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&area=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
});
```

and you already registered the custom query variable, next is (because you're in development) go to `admin > settings > permalinks` and save settings to flush the rewrite rules.

Now to get the custom `area`, just call `get_query_arg('area')` which will return the value when WP_Query is ready.

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly, thanks Samuel! Note to others: just add Samuel's code to your functions.php file in your theme.

Comment: You're welcome! Have a good day bobby :)